# Acknowledgement About Batch Files and Codes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm Writing a Batch File. And I am Use this Command;

```
set /p cmd="Enter Command here = "
if "%cmd%"=="Help" goto Help
if "%cmd%"=="Exit" goto Exit
```

But i really Don't Know About these Codes a bit

Means , I want to Know if i can Remove " " of `"%cmd%"` or if I use a Command like this

```
if "%cmd%"=="install apple itunes" goto itunes
```

Batch File Crashes But When i Use 
`if "%cmd%"=="install apple.itunes" goto itunes` i.e apple itunes without spaces it works Fine
Can SomeOne Please Tell Me about these Codes and how to use `if "%cmd%"=="install apple itunes"` i.e With Spaces.

Comment: If you think they are going to put double quotes around their input then just test for the existence of them or put the variable into a FOR command to strip them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not remove `" "` from `"%cmd%"`. If user inputs "install apple itunes" in the cmd variable, the if condition should work.